# user32 ChangeDisplaySettings issue

Tags: c#, windows-10, resolution

I want to change screen resolution.

```
public CResolution(int a,int b)
{
  int iWidth = a;
  int iHeight =b;

  DEVMODE1 dm = new DEVMODE1();
  dm.dmDeviceName = new String (new char[32]);
  dm.dmFormName = new String (new char[32]);
  dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf (dm);

  if (0 != User_32.EnumDisplaySettings (null, User_32.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm))
  {
    dm.dmPelsWidth = iWidth;
    dm.dmPelsHeight = iHeight;

    int iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings (ref dm, User_32.CDS_TEST);
  }
}
```

Resolution changed but now in some applications in windows icons are small and textboxes and buttons mix, but most applications are good.

this is a screenshot of my pc.
https://42cdn.com/b2api/v1/b2_download_file_by_id?fileId=4_z6177fca890d8c37157cc0814_f1111fcbfec565153_d20180116_m075053_c001_v0001100_t0053

Comment: What windows version are you running?

Comment: windows 10.....

Comment: Can you edit you question and add information about the values for the different fields in you `DEVMODE` structure when you're changing the display mode.

Comment: Sounds like a mixture of high-DPI settings and non-DPI aware applications. Windows generally does a decent job of hiding the worst behaviours but they do sometimes leak through.

Comment: i dont set any value for **DEVMODE**except **dmDeviceName **,**dmFormName** ,**dmSize**

Comment: a photo of my problem https://42cdn.com/b2api/v1/b2_download_file_by_id?fileId=4_z6177fca890d8c37157cc0814_f1111fcbfec565153_d20180116_m075053_c001_v0001100_t0053

Comment: Doing a search on `SSMS DPI Issues` reveals plenty of reports of these kind of symptoms. So, what's you're actual question?

Comment: some apps has this dpi issue after running my code.not just sql

Comment: Yes. Yes they do. That's an *observation*, not a *question*. Some applications aren't well behaved in high-DPI situations (as I indicated in my first comment). Neither we nor you can remedy this, if the resolution you're switching to is the one that you want. Only the authors of those other applications *could* fix them, but they haven't (currently) chosen to do so, at least in the versions of those applications you have installed. They *may* have released later versions that are properly DPI aware. But again, we can't do anything about this.

Comment: but apps after my code excecution have this issue and changing resolution to first settings doesn correct any things.

Comment: and ssms dpi issue for other users that you mention is that **icons and the text in the SSMS are looking blurry**  .my broblem is diffrence